# Adding to the year when January might not be detected

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

In short, I have a page where I can set up how clients will be paying me.

**http://i.imgur.com/N6IuX2Y.png**

I can choose how many instalments they can make, and whether or not they will pay me monthly or bimonthly (every second month).

I have it now, so that the months change perfectly, but getting the year to change for the bimonthly frequency is proving to be difficult.

Obviously, January should always add +1 the the current year... But using the bimonthly option means January might not be available to detect, so I will have to use February... which is fine, unless I start the bill on December which causes me a lot of trouble.

When starting the bill on December 2014, February will be 2015, but April will be back to 2014.. I can't figure this part out.

Here I have a fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/amd9fcjf/**

```
var schedule = [];

function test() {
billingDate = document.getElementById("billingDate").value;
startMonth = parseFloat(billingDate.split("-")[1]);
startYear = parseFloat(billingDate.split("-")[0]);
frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
instalments = document.getElementById("instalments").value;
months = ["janvier", "f&eacute;vrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "ao&ucirc;t", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "d&eacute;cembre"];

for (var i = 0; i < instalments; i++) {

    if (frequency === "monthly") {
        mm = months[parseFloat((i + startMonth - 1) % 12)];
        // If the month is ever January, increase the year by 1
        if (mm === months[0] && startMonth != 1) // if the first month isn't January
        {
            yyyy = startYear + 1;
        } else {
            yyyy = startYear;
        }
        schedule.push(mm + "-" + yyyy);

    } else {

        // frequency === "bimonthly"
        mm = months[parseFloat(((i * 2) + startMonth - 1) % 12)];
        if ((mm === months[0] && startMonth != 1) || (mm === months[1] && startMonth != 2)) {
            yyyy = startYear + 1;
            console.log("Start Month ! January/February, year + 1");
        } else {
            yyyy = startYear;
        }
        schedule.push(mm + "-" + yyyy);
    }

}
console.log(schedule);
document.getElementById("depositDates").innerHTML = schedule;
}
```

Edit:

I cleaned up a bit, sort of, and I decided (for now) to use the ++var method, and just limit myself from offering too many instalments (pretty much hiding the fact that the year wont change when selecting bi-monthly and the startMonth is Jan/Feb). So if the month is Feb, I can only offer 6 instalments, not too bad.

```
var schedule = [];

function paySchedule() {
total = document.getElementById("total").value;
billingDate = document.getElementById("billingDate").value;
startMonth = parseFloat(billingDate.split("-")[1]);
startYear = parseFloat(billingDate.split("-")[0]);
frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
instalments = document.getElementById("instalments").value;
months = ["janvier", "f&eacute;vrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "ao&ucirc;t", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "d&eacute;cembre"];
payments = (total / instalments).toFixed(2);
yyyy = startYear;
for (var i = 0; i < instalments; i++) {
    if (frequency === "monthly") {
        mm = months[parseFloat((i + startMonth - 1) % 12)];
        // get months by number
        monthNum = months.indexOf(mm);
        // check if month is January
        if (monthNum === 0) {
            console.log("Jan detected, year + 1");
            // add another year
            yyyy = startYear + 1;
        }
        schedule.push(payments + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy);
    } else // important, make sure the user can only input a maximum of 6 instalments
    {
        // frequency === "bimonthly"
        mm = months[parseFloat(((i * 2) + startMonth - 1) % 12)];
        // get months by number
        monthNum = months.indexOf(mm);
        // check if month is January or February
        if ((monthNum === 0 || monthNum === 1) && startMonth != 1 && startMonth != 2) {
            // add another year
            yyyy = ++startYear;
        }
        schedule.push(payments + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy);
    }
}
console.log(schedule);
document.getElementById("depositDates").value = schedule;
}
```

Comment: So far everything within the IF statement is working fine (from what I can see), it's the else statement that sucks for me. startYear++ will continuously add to the year for every iteration it seems, e.g.: dec2014,jan2015,feb2016

Comment: with http://momentjs.com/ that would be a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only change the value of the year for the month you're changing it in, not for all coming months.

You can fix your issue by replacing the two lines

```
yyyy = startYear + 1;
```

with

```
yyyy = ++startYear;
```

, but that is just a dirty fix and obscures what is happening. You could add the starting month and year to the schedule first, decrement `installments` and then just always increment `yyyy` whenever you're in January (or in February when it's bi-monthly), getting rid of `startMonth` and `startYear` entirely.